# Unexpected response from the server. The file may have been uploaded successfully. Check in the Media Library or reload the page

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, media-library

I couldn't find an answer to this in other relevant threads.

I'm trying to upload a PDF (1.4 MB) to WordPress using the media uploader and I get this response:

Unexpected response from the server. The file may have been uploaded successfully. Check in the Media Library or reload the page.

This is on shared linux hosting at Godaddy.

What I've tried:

- Disable each plugin individually
- Change to wordpress twentytwenty theme
- Raised config settings in user.ini

  max_execution_time
  upload_max_filesize
  post_max_size
  max_input_vars
  memory_limit
  client_max_body_size
- Log in incognito mode
- Clean install of wordpress on live server
- Changed wp-content and uploads (+ subdirectories) file permissions to 755
- Made async-upload.php DOING_AJAX without if statements

The error log shows nothing.

In the server logs I have found a 404 for async-upload.php,
which I suspect is the root of the problem, but I don't know what to do with it. (async-upload.php file is definately there).

Does anyone have any advice on this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you see in the browser console and network panel? _“(async-upload.php file is definately there)”_ - definitively _where_? Are you sure URL path and filesystem location match?

Comment: Yes they definately match. In the console I have an XHR  for http://example.com/wp-admin/async-upload.php, and in network panel its the same. The file does exist at that location.

Comment: The network panel doens't show any response returned, there's no status code to go with it.

Comment: Have you checked the server _error_ log? (That 404 you mentioned, is probably rather from the access log, I suppose.) Also make sure full PHP error reporting is enabled, and WP put into debug mode.

Comment: I ended up solving it with the host's help. The problem was a corrupted PDF file. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a corrupted PDF. The first thing I should have checked.